# How to save a dirty record without changing the BindingSource position

Tags: ado.net

I have a `BindingSource` that is used as a `DataSource` in some bound form controls.

Now I want to save the changes that I have entered in the form. This is the code to save the changes.

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    Using connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim dataAdapterReminders = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Reminders", connection)
        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapterReminders)
        dataAdapterReminders.Update(dataSetReminders, "Reminders")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Only it does not work exactly as I want to.

The code above only save the form data **if** I move the BindingSource cursor (forward, backwards - doesnt really matter). If I dont move the BindingSource cursor then

```
Me.dataSetReminders.GetChanges(DataRowState.Modified)
```

returns `Nothing|null` and there is nothing to update.

How can I enforce the writing of a dirty record|row?

Answer (score 0):

The solution seems to be to get a hold of the DataRowView and `EndEdit`

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    Using connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        Dim drv = CType(bindSourceReminders.Current, DataRowView)
        drv.EndEdit()

        connection.Open()
        Dim dataAdapterReminders = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Reminders", connection)
        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommandBuilder(dataAdapterReminders)
        dataAdapterReminders.Update(dataSetReminders, "Reminders")
    End Using
```

End Sub